# How do I correctly make one constructor's prototype property inherit its original's prototype property?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am a newbie in javascript programming. Recently I come across a problem confusing me in my javascript journey. 
I want to create a Teacher() constructor, which inherits all the members from Person() constructor.

First, I create Person() as following

```
    function Person(name) {
      this.name = name;
    };

    Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
      alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
    };
```

Second I create Teacher() from Person().

```
    function Teacher(name){
      Person.call(this,name);
    };
```

Here is the problem:

When I tried to set Teacher()'s prototype, it confused me that following two practices seem to be the same. However they must have some difference, I think.
I wrote as following first:

```
    Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

After I wrote as above, I think Teacher.prototype would be equal to Person.prototype, which proved to be wrong:

```
    Teacher.prototype === Person.prototype;//=>false
```

However, teacherA, the instance of Teacher(), inherits greeting method from Person() successfully:

```
    var teacherA = new Teacher();
    teacherA.name = 'Kyle';
    teacherA.greeting();//=>Hi!I'm Kyle.
```

Then I tried to change my code as following, which made Teacher()'s prototype property equal to Person()'s prototype property:

```
    Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
    Teacher.prototype === Person.prototype;//=>true
```

Certainly, teacherB, another instance of Teacher(), inherits greeting method from Person() as well:

```
    var teacherB = new Teacher();
    teacherB.name = 'Jane';
    teacherB.greeting();//=>Hi!I'm Jane.
```

Anybody can tell me why these two practices both made inheriting successfully, but in one of two situations Teacher.prototype was not equal to Person.prototype, which is opposite in another situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After I wrote as above, I think Teacher.prototype would be equal to
>   Person.prototype, which proved to be wrong

Yes, because when you use `Object.create` it creates new object with the prototype being `Person.prototype`. This is sort of what happens:

```
var mediator = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(mediator, Person.prototype);
Teacher.prototype = mediator
```

So the resulting prototype chain is like this:

```
Teacher.prototype -> middle.__proto__ -> Person.prototype
```

> However, teacherA, the instance of Teacher(), inherits greeting method
>   from Person() successfully:

Yes, because as I've showed above the `Person.prototype` can still be reached from `Teacher.prototype`.

> Then I tried to change my code as following, which made Teacher()'s
>   prototype property equal to Person()'s prototype property:

This should not be done, because you may want to add methods to Teacher prototype that should not be acccessible from Person. But by doing so, if you add any method to Teacher prototype, it will be accessible from the instances of Person. So, after doing so:

```
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;

var teacher = new Teacher();
var person = new Person();

// let's add method to child Person
Person.prototype.childMethod = function() {};

// the parent can still access it
person.childMethod(); // works OK
```

Comment: Your answer is really informative. Bearing this in mind when I learn will definitely make me understand inheritance better. Thank you so much.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that when you wrote: